# Making Bootstrap Carousel start on window load, after loading gif is done

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have portfolio with a GIF displaying till the page is loaded. The problem, is that under the GIF, the Bootstrap Carousel is sliding images even before everything is loaded, so by the time the loading GIF disappears, the carousel is already displaying image 5 or 6, not the first one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
      pause: "false",
      interval: 8000
  });

  $('.carousel').css({'margin': 0, 'width': $(window).outerWidth(), 'height': $(window).outerHeight()});
  $('.carousel .item').css({'position': 'fixed', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'});
  $('.carousel-inner div.item img').each(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().css({'background': 'url('+imgSrc+') center center no-repeat', '-webkit-background-size': '100% ', '-moz-background-size': '100%', '-o-background-size': '100%', 'background-size': '100%', '-webkit-background-size': 'cover', '-moz-background-size': 'cover', '-o-background-size': 'cover', 'background-size': 'cover'});
    $(this).remove();
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.carousel').css({'width': $(window).outerWidth(), 'height': $(window).outerHeight()});
  });
});
```

I've tried to modify the code to:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
      pause: "false",
      interval: 8000
  });
```

With this last code, once the site is loaded it will display the first image, but the carousel won't start.

Here's my Html:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

And the Loading gif JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  })
//]]>
</script>
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On my mobile so limited with my reply but I would try chaining them so the carousel fires on completion of the gif animations and delays.

Comment: Actually, just like the answer below, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the callback function of your fadeout to call the carousel. Something like this.

```
$('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel({
      pause: "false",
      interval: 8000
  });
  // more here
});
```

This will call the function after the preloader is faded.

Comment: This solution works, but weirdly enough, will kill the pause: "false" and the set interval.

Answer (score 1):

Natewiley and Joe, your solution was solving my problem, but killing the attributes set for the carousel. Following your example, I added the following code into the fadeOut.

```
$('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $( "#carousel-example-generic" ).attr('data-ride', "carousel");
});
```

As the carousel will only start when containing the data-ride="carousel", I just add it when the fadeOut is triggered. On the background, the other piece of js will still initialize the carousel and set its attributes, but it will only start when the data-attribute is set.

So, thanks Joe and Nate for the help! : ))